# Can we post/send data from Windows Forms Application to Android application?

Tags: android, winforms

I have my Windows Forms Application in c# 4.0, I wanted to post/send data to an android application. It need to triggered from Windows Forms.

Any one can suggest me the possible ways to do this?

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use the WebClient class. Depending on the "payload", you can use of of the UploadXXX methods.

For example:

```
string URL = "..."; //Your url here
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
formData["Username"] = "myusername";
formData["Password"] = "mypassword";
byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
string Result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
```

Cheers

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. I have a window application, and android is also an application. I didn't understand "string URL = "..."; //Your url here".

Comment: You asked how to "post" data to an Android app, so maybe I assumed wrongly that there would be some kind of web server process on the phone listening to http connections. Am I wrong ? Otherwise, how were you planning to connect to the Android app ?